# bitly raise error exception rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, bit.ly

I'm trying to write a simple rspec test for bitly raise error exception. How can I write the expect to match the error message `ALREADY_A_BITLY_LINK - '500'` with the `raise_error(BitlyError)`. This rspec actually pass. But if I were to use the same raise_error for invalid URL. It will also pass. How can I test the specific exception message?

bitly_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Bitly do
  before do
    @bitly = Bitly.new(username, api_key)
  end
  let(:bitly_url) { 'bitly_url' } #stackoverflow doesn't allow URL shortener

  it 'should return exception error if given url is bitly' do
    expect { @bitly.shorten(bitly_url) }.to raise_error(BitlyError)
  end
end
```

Debugger

`@bitly.shorten(bitly_url)` returns `*** BitlyError Exception: ALREADY_A_BITLY_LINK - '500'`

`raise_error(BitlyError)` returns `#<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::RaiseError:0x007fa229c56f48 @block=nil, @actual_error=nil, @warn_about_bare_error=false, @expected_error=BitlyError, @expected_message=nil>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the docs - https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher - the raise error matcher  can take a second parameter of string or regex to match against the exceptions message

```
expect { whatever }.to raise_error(BitlyError, "ALREADY_A_BITLY_LINK")
```